# R caret: fully reproducible results with parallel rfe on different machines

Tags: random, parallel-processing, random-forest, r-caret, random-seed

I have the following code using random forest as method which is fully reproducible if you run it in parallel mode on the same machine:

```
library(doParallel)
library(caret)

recursive_feature_elimination <- function(dat){

  all_preds <- dat[,which(names(dat) %in% c("Time", "Chick", "Diet"))]
  response <- dat[,which(names(dat) == "weight")]

  sizes <- c(1:(ncol(all_preds)-1))

  # set seeds manually
  set.seed(42, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion")
  # an optional vector of integers for the size. The vector should have length of length(sizes)+1
  # length is n_repeats*nresampling+1
  seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = 16)
  for(i in 1:15) seeds[[i]]<- sample.int(n=1000, size = length(sizes)+1)
  # for the last model
  seeds[[16]]<-sample.int(1000, 1)
  seeds_list <- list(rfe_seeds = seeds,
                     train_seeds = NA)

  # specify rfeControl
  contr <- caret::rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="repeatedcv", number=3, repeats=5, 
                             saveDetails = TRUE, seeds = seeds, allowParallel = TRUE)

  # recursive feature elimination caret 
  results <- caret::rfe(x = all_preds, 
                        y = response,
                        sizes = sizes, 
                        method ="rf",
                        ntree = 250, 
                        metric= "RMSE", 
                        rfeControl=contr )


 return(results)


}

dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)

cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(cores, outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)
results <- recursive_feature_elimination(dat)
stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
```

The outcome on my machine is:

```
 Variables  RMSE Rsquared   MAE RMSESD RsquaredSD MAESD Selected
         1 39.14   0.6978 24.60  2.755    0.02908 1.697         
         2 23.12   0.8998 13.90  2.675    0.02273 1.361        *
         3 28.18   0.8997 20.32  2.243    0.01915 1.225         

The top 2 variables (out of 2):
   Time, Chick
```

I am using a Windows OS with one CPU and 4 cores. If the code is run on a UNIX OS using multiple CPUs with multiple cores, the outcome is different. I think this behaviour shows up because of the random number generation, which obviously differs between my system and the multi-CPU system. The same happens with `train()`.

How can I get fully reproducible results independent of the OS and independent of how many CPUs and cores used for parallelization?

How can I assure that the same random numbers are used for each internal process of `rfe` and `randomForest` no matter in which sequence during the parallel computing the process is run?

How are the random numbers generated for each parallel process?

Comment: I am not sure this is possible. Especially for the part `independent of how many CPUs and cores used for parallelization`. I fully embrace the fact my results can not be exactly reproduced when I am performing in parallel anything that is not very simple. In this case I would be content if  different runs pick the same features. If reproducibility is the main goal why not perform on a single core? By the way why are you doing rfe with rf if you just have three features? Perhaps it would be better to tune rf hyper parameters?

Comment: It is just an example. I have more than 200 features. It would be great to make the results reproducible in parallel mode. Of course the number of CPUs and cores are known. But I need the same results from a machine with 1 CPU and 4 cores as from a machine with for example 5 CPUs each having 20 cores.